# How does spring know to use jackson for serialization even if i just added that dependency in maven, no more anything?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

i just added jackson dependency in maven, no more anything and spring start to use it for marshalling without any additional code configuration, How does spring know to use jackson for serialization

Comment: can you post your spring config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer - if it's on the class path.

longer answer -

if you are using `@EnableWebMvc` it calls [DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.html) which extends [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) which uses

```
private static final boolean jackson2Present =
        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader()) &&
                ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator", WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader());
```

to see if Jackson is in the class path.  this boolean is used in various places including `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`